# How to prevent the text in Django Admin to get bigger when overriding "base.css" set in overridden "base.html"?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-staticfiles

I could change the header color to black in all admin pages with the following steps.

So, this is Django Admin as shown below:

[image]

Then, I copied [base.css](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css) from `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css` in my virtual environment to `core/static/core/admin/css/` and copied [base.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) from `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html` to `templates/admin/` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-static
 |     └-core
 |        └-admin
 |           └-css
 |              └-base.css # Here
 |-app1
 |-app2
 └-templates
    └-admin
       └-base.html # Here
```

Then in `base.css`, I replaced `background: var(--header-bg);` with `background: black;` as shown below:

```css
/* "core/static/core/admin/css/base.css" */ 

#header {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    /* background: var(--header-bg); */
    background: black; /* Here */
    color: var(--header-color);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then in [{% static %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#static) in `base.html`, I replaced `admin/css/base.css` with `core/admin/css/base.css` as shown below to change the header color to black in all admin pages:

```
# "templates/admin/base.html"

# ...                                                      {# "admin/css/base.css" is replaced #}
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>             {# ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ #}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "core/admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">
{% block dark-mode-vars %}
#...
```

Then, I could change the header color to black in all admin pages but the text gets bigger than the original one as shown below.

After:
[image]

Before(Original):
[image]

So in `base.html`, I added `type="text/css"` and `media="all"` to `<link>` as shown below but the text is still bigger than the original one:

```
# "templates/admin/base.html"

# ...
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "core/admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">
{% block dark-mode-vars %} {# ↑ Here #}  {# ↑ Here #}
#...
```

So, how can I prevent the text in Django Admin to get bigger when overriding `base.css` set in the overridden `base.html`?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `<link ... "core/admin/css/base.css" %}">` after `<link ... "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">` without replacing `admin/css/base.css` with `core/admin/css/base.css` in [{% static %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#static) in [base.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) as shown below to change the header color to black in all admin pages:

```
# "templates/admin/base.html"

# ...
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "core/admin/css/base.css" %}"> {# Here #}
{% block dark-mode-vars %}
#...
```

Then, you can prevent the text in Django Admin to get bigger when overriding `base.css` set in the overridden `base.html` as shown below:

After:
[image]

Before(Original):
[image]